# Realsense depth calibration

Tags: ros, realsense, depth-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey All,

I am using a Realsense F200 with the realsense_camera package for 3D mapping. The camera doesn't provide registered depth images, which everything seems to need. I looked at the depth_image_proc package but it requires rectified depth and rgb images as well as the calibration data. I should be able to calibrate the rgb camera with the camera_calibration package, but how do I calibrate the depth camera? I looked at how to do it for the [Kinect](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration) but I don't think that will work for the Realsense as I just get a black image when I cover the laser projector. If anyone knows how to calibrate the depth camera or get registered depth images out of this camera I could use the help.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230545/realsense-depth-calibration/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2016-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

So it turns out that the Realsense cameras are factory calibrated with the calibration parameters onboard the camera. The [realsense_camera](https://github.com/BlazingForests/realsense_camera)  package I am using doesn't access this data directly. The official Intel [realsense](https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense) package does access this data but does not support the F200. I was able to get the calibration parameters by editing the official package so it would work on the F200. Once I had the calibration parameters I used the realsense_camera package with those, resized the depth image to match the rgb image, then used depth_image_proc to register them. It's not perfect due to the resizing but it works well enough.

[EDIT]
The built in calibration parameters are very close to what I found using camera_calibration and probably don't need changed unless you require very precise results.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Isa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29778/isa/) on 2017-03-22**:
Hi,

Were you able to calibrate the F200? I have been trying to perform a similar calibration as the one done for the kinect (http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration) but I haven't succeded because the F200 doesn't have the service set_camera_info ().

Thanks,

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2017-10-02**:
We wound up using a laser scanner instead so I did the bother continuing with this.